# Setuptools version Python mismatch on Shippable

Tags: pip, shippable-ci

I can't tell exactly where my problem is arising, but as of about a week ago I've been unable to deploy my Node app via Shippable.

I was running an older version of Node when the issue first arose. Since then I've tried to upgrade my Node version to 10.21.0 and the same issues present. I've also tried to mess with different version of things in my shippable file to no avail

The error I get it

```
Downloading/unpacking setuptools>=20.0 (from awsebcli==3.7.8)
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/setuptools/setup.py) egg_info for package setuptools
    pkg_resources/py2_warn.py:15: UserWarning: Setuptools no longer works on Python 2
```

I tried several things in my shippable file, pasted in full below, commenting out the bits that did't help. I also tried to target the version for setuptools but that gave a different error

```
# python:
#   - 2.7

node_js:
  - 10.21.0   
  
install:
  - shippable_retry npm install
  - npm install -g gulp
  # - pip uninstall -y setuptools
  # - pip install setuptools=42.0.2
  # - pip install --force-reinstall awsebcli==3.14.5
  # - pip install --force-reinstall botocore==1.11.9
```

I'm perfectly content sticking with python2 but don't know how to tell Shippable to use the older version of setuptools. Or I'm perfectly content upgrading to python3 but don't know how to tell shippable to do that.

I tried to follow the instructions on https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python%202%20sunset.html but they didn't seem to cooperate with shippable

Comment: `pip install setuptools==42.0.2` (double the equal sign) or even better `pip install 'setuptools<44'`

Comment: okay so it moved the error farther down now @phd I think we're close, now I get the same error but it's after `Downloading/unpacking setuptools>=20.0 (from awsebcli==3.7.8) Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/setuptools/setup.py) egg_info for package setuptools pkg_resources/py2_warn.py:15: UserWarning: Setuptools no longer works on Python 2`

Comment: It seems `pkg_resources` (a part of `setuptools`) was not updated. Let's do it with `pip install --upgrade --upgrade-strategy=eager 'setuptools<44'` or even with `pip install --force-reinstall 'setuptools<44'`

Comment: @phd for the first choice I got `no such option: --upgrade-strategy` and got the same error from an hour ago on the 2nd option